# constraints with c++20 concepts

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I'm trying to understand C++20 concepts, in particular the example from [here](https://oleksandrkvl.github.io/2021/04/02/cpp-20-overview.html#concepts). Why is it an error if we're templatizing `f` with a concept that's stricter than allowed? In other words doesn't `Integral4` also satisfy the `Integral` concept?

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <concepts>

template<typename T>
concept Integral = std::integral<T>;

template<typename T>
concept Integral4 = Integral<T> && sizeof(T) == 4;

template<template<Integral T1> typename T>
void f(){
}

template<typename T>
struct S1{};

template<Integral T>
struct S2{};

template<Integral4 T>
struct S3{};

void test(){
    f<S1>();    // OK
    f<S2>();    // OK
    // error, S3 is constrained by Integral4 which is more constrained than
    // f()'s Integral
    f<S3>();
}
```

Error

```cpp
<source>: In function 'void test()':
<source>:28:10: error: no matching function for call to 'f<template<class T>  requires  Integral4<T> struct S3>()'
   28 |     f<S3>();
      |     ~~~~~^~
<source>:11:6: note: candidate: 'template<template<class T1> class requires  Integral<T1> T> void f()'
   11 | void f(){
      |      ^
<source>:11:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>:28:10: error: constraint mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<template<class T1> class requires  Integral<T1> T> void f()'
   28 |     f<S3>();
      |     ~~~~~^~
<source>:28:10: note:   expected 'template<class T1> class requires  Integral<T1> T' but got 'template<class T>  requires  Integral4<T> struct S3'
Compiler returned: 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`f` takes a template template parameter that is constrained on `Integral`. This means that `f` is allowed to use any type `T` which satisfies `Integral` on this template.

For example, `short`.

`S3` is a type constrained on `Integral4`, which subsumes `Integral`. This means that, while any type `U` which satisfies `Integral4` will also satisfy `Integral`, the *reverse* is not true. There are some types `T` which satisfy `Integral` but *not* `Integral4`

`short` for example is `Integral`, but it is unlikely to satisfy `Integral4`.

But `f` has the right to use `short` on the template it is provided, because that's what its signature says it can do. Since `S3` provided only allows a *subset* of the types that `f`'s signature allows it to use, you get a compile error.